# Cloud Foundry - cf logs throws websocket errors

Tags: cloud-foundry

When using Cloud Foundry with api version 2.0.0, and cf-cli 6.26, the command `cf logs <APPNAME> -v` produces the following error:

```
REQUEST: [2017-05-19T13:28:35+01:00]
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: 
Accept: application/json
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: cf/6.26.0+9c9a261.2017-04-06 (go1.7.5; amd64 linux)
[PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]

WEBSOCKET ERROR: [2017-05-19T13:28:35+01:00]
Post /oauth/token: unsupported protocol scheme "". Retrying...
```

Answer (score 0):

Either upgrade the Cloud Foundry installation, or downgrade the CLI (version 6.21.1 works for me).

Cloud Foundry changed the configuration of the endpoints used for logging at some point. https://www.pivotaltracker.com/n/projects/966314/stories/135557875

Version 6.26 of cf-cli expects `doppler_logging_endpoint` to be set, whereas v2.0.0 of the API only sends `loggregator_endpoint`. Thus the Websocket Request is sent to "", which results in the response being nonsense, generating this error.